# When i redirect to search page, can i fill the form (post method) in Response? It's possible? How?

Tags: .net, forms, post, redirect, fill

When i catch a invalid URL, for example: **www.example.com/urlDontExists** , i redirect to the Search Page, like this:

```
Response.Redirect("/Search");
```

Bu i want to send the tag "urlDontExists", to the form, to see the same result like i went to the Search page, and searched by "urlDontExists".

I know it's possible with QueryString like:

```
Response.Redirect("/Search?searchtag=urlDontExists");
```

But i don't want in the QueryString

This it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the parameters and fill the search form here
    var location = window.location;
    // modify the querystring so that urlDoesntExist is removed from the titlebar
    ...
    window.location.replace(modified_url);
})
```

Note that this is a big hack.